# checking the map between managed property names and their associated site column/s inside SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, crawling, managed-property, crawled-property

I am working on a sharepoint server 2013, now i create a new Web Part of type Search Content Web Part. where inside the query builder i got a drop-down menu to select a property name as follow:-

[image]

now i always have some difficulties in understanding the following:-

1- how i can see the map between the actual site columns and the property name inside the above property drop down list?

2- from my own test i can see that a single property name can reference multiple site columns even when these site columns exists inside different site collections. for example i have three site collections, and inside each site collection i have a site column name "Item Number". now when i select a property named "`ItemNumberOWSTEXT` " , and define the following criteria (`ItemNumberOWSTEXT:-T-`) :-

[image]

i got items from different site collections which have their item number fields containing "`-T-`", so in other word the `ItemNumberOWSTEXT`  property is actually refereeing multiple site columns from multiple site collections? so is this possible and how i can check these?

**EDIT**

not sure how things can go crazy easily in sharepoint .. now i went to "Central administration" >> "Managed Services" >> "Search Service" >> "crawl properties"and i search for the word `number`, i got these results:-

[image]

now i can not understand the following 2 points:-

1- as i mentioned before i have three site columns inside three site collections which have their internal names as follow:-

```
- ItemNumber
- ItemNumber
- Item_X0020_Number
```

but inside the crawl properties i got 2 crawl properties named `ows_itemNumber` & `ows_item_x0020_number` ,, so there is missing `ows_itemnumber`. as i should have three crawl properties representing my three site columns .is this correct?

2- Second point. not sure what does `ows_q_txt_ItemNumber` crawl property represent? As it is mapped to a manged property unlike the other properties . and inside my Content Search web part when i wrote the following inside my query `ItemNumberOWSTEXT:-T-` i got results from the 3 site collections items , where these items have their "item number" contain `-T-`?? so not sure what is going on !!

Comment: In the search admin center in central administration is where all of this schema is defined

Comment: @EricAlexander can you please provide more detail now not sure what you mean by "search admin  center".. now i access my central admin >> managed services >>search service >> Crawled Properties.. where i can see all the crawl and managed properties ,, but not sure how i can check their related site columns.. or if i can search for a site column and then see its related managed and crawl properties!!

Comment: @EricAlexander now in other words from the central administration, i can view the map between crawl properties and managed properties ,, but i can NOT view the map between crawl properties and site columns or between managed properties and site columns,, hope this clarify  what i am asking for .. thanks

Comment: The crawled properties are the site columns.  If you go to Central Admin, manage the Search Service, and look at crawled properties, you will see a filter drop down.  Choose "SharePoint", and you should see crawled properties that represent the site columns.  In general they have a naming pattern of "ows_FieldInternalName".

Comment: @DylanCristy ok thanks for the info ,, but unfortunatly things are not straight forward ,, can you please check my edit ?

Comment: Regarding your additional question 1 - I don't think there would be two with the same name, even though you have two columns in two different site collections, they have the same internal name, so there will be only one crawled property with that name.  Regarding your second question - seems like the "...q_TEXT..." are autogenerated by SharePoint as part of the process of generating managed properties.  [See this article that explains the process a bit.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx)

Comment: Regarding why you get results from all three site collections - I think that's the way it's supposed to work.  You *should* be able to aggregate content from multiple site collections through Search.  If you want your results to only come from a particular site collection, you will have to do some other kind of filtering in the CSWP, either by setting up a result source, or using "PATH" in the query itself.

Comment: @DylanCristy but my question is from where i should find the info that ows_q_txt_ItemNumber property is actually referencing three site columns !!! now i know i should be able to aggregate conent from multiple site collection,, but i did not define any aggregation,, but at the same time i am getting aggregated results,, so my question is how i can view how the aggregation is working and where it is defined!!1

Comment: I don't think it's "defined" anywhere.  The crawled properties and managed properties are based on column names, that's it.  They don't take into account the location of the columns.  So as soon as you have two site columns on two sites with the same name, that data is going to get associated with the same crawled/managed property in search.  In a certain sense, you *did* define the aggregation by creating site columns with the same name.

Comment: @DylanCristy So based on this could the senario I faced is as follow. Now I have define three site columns ; which have the following INTERNAL names Item_X0020_number & ItemNumber & also ItemNumber. Now I got the following internal name “Item_X0020_number” since using the UI I defined the site column named to be “Item Number”. so as a result I got a single crawled property named ows_q_txt_ItemNumber representing the 3 site columns, because in this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx

Comment: @DylanCristy .... it mentioned that when building crawled properties the white spaces will be removed, then it will be prefixed with ows_q_. So actually the three site columns in my case “item Number” & 2 “ItemNumber” are being represented by a single managed property , which is ows_q_txt_ItemNumber ??

Comment: Crawled property names are always unique. However, one managed property can be mapped to multiple crawled properties. Regarding your second question: which crawled property is mapped to which site column, you can simple create three separate managed property for each crawled property and then use all 3 managed properties in you web part. Now by looking at each managed property values in search results, you can check which property is mapped to which site column.

Comment: @Yayati can you please check my above 2 comments start with (So based on this could .....),, where i tried to describe what i assumed actually happened inside my sharepoint web application ?? is my scenario valid ?